# same struct different files

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, struct

I've got a little problem.
I have 2 files: one.c and two.c
they both decler and implement the struct: StackNode
the header files are:
one.h:

```
 #ifndef ONE_H
 #define ONE_H

 typedef struct StackNode StackNode;
 #endif
```

two.h:

```
 #ifndef TWO_H
 #define TWO_H

 #include "one.h"

 #endif
```

cpp files:
one.c:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <malloc.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include "one.h"

 struct StackNode
 {
   ........
 };
```

two.c:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <malloc.h>
 #include "two.h"
 struct StackNode
 {
   ........
 };
```

Why this compile and run in linox but in visual stutio it says:
two.obj : error LNK2005: "struct StackNode * top" (?top@@3PAUStackNode@@A) already defined in one.obj
1>c:\users\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Exercise\Debug\Exercise.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

What can I do so it will work in  visual too?
Thank you :)

Comment: Change the name or put them in different namespaces (or make them the same and only have one definition).

Comment: but why/how it's working on linux?

Comment: And why are you including `malloc.h` in c++?

Comment: I use alocation later in those files.. 
That was just an exemple

Comment: @user3169750 `Linux` is not a C++ compiler.  You probably mean `g++`.

Comment: Oh, I was assuming you were using `malloc` or other C memory allocation functions, but the question is "Why are you using `malloc` or other C memory allocation functions in C++"? (There *are* some valid reasons, but ...)

Comment: @user3169750 So what is `sizeof(StackNode)` in your application?  Is it sizeof(StackNode) in one.cpp, or is it sizeof(StackNode) in two.cpp?   In short, don't do what you're doing now - -it will lead to weird bugs.  What if you called `new StackNode` in one.cpp, and you passed that pointer to a function defined in two.cpp and two.cpp dereferences that pointer?   See the issues?  Just define two different structs, or use the very same struct.

Comment: my mistake.. it's c not c++,,

Comment: @user3169750 Whether it's C or C++, doesn't matter.  You may be passing pointers (or even StackNode's) between functions defined in one.c and two.c.  That is *not* going to work out nice for you.

Comment: You should state clear it is C, not C++ by at least removing any C++/CPP references from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker does not say that the structure itself is defined twice. It says that object `top` is defined twice like `struct StackNode * top`. You have to define it only in one compilation unit.

> two.obj : error LNK2005: "**struct StackNode * top**"
>   (?top@@3PAUStackNode@@A) already defined in one.obj